# Can't rename/move files from OSX that were copied from NTFS

Tags: linux, macos, permissions, ntfs

I recently had data recovered and it was sent back to me on what I think is an NTFS drive. I copied all the files over to a file share I have on a Linux box, that's ext4. 
Now I have that share mounted on my OSX machine, and I can't move or rename most of the files. However, in a couple cases I was able to rename a folder after the third try. Another time I was able to rename a folder once, but not again. All the permissions are showing up the same on the command-line -- I can't see any differences between the permissions on any of the files/folders.

Note that I can create new folders and add files no problem, and then rename and move those all I want.

Any clues???

Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing this through the command line or a GUI? Is there a specific error from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Try to select a file that has been causing problems and right-click it in Finder, then select `Get Info`. In the pop-up window, see if the `Locked` option is checked, and try to deselect it (it may require authentication).

To note that even if the POSIX permissions are the same, the files may have different ACLs that take precedence. You can see what they are by opening a Terminal window (`Applications` > `Utilities`), navigating to the folder that contains some of the problem files, and typing `ls -le`. Post that output here if the first suggestions doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem, and I found the 'Locked' box checked when I do Get Info from finder.  However, I find it annoying to have to do such things outside the terminal..

See this apple article:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1526,
section:  Advanced tip about deleting locked files

which will direct you to:         `chflags -R nouchg` *files*

`ls -l` won't show any difference, but `ls -lO` will (that's capital oh).
`man chflags` for more info

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450745/certain-files-in-finder-cannot-be-opened-renamed-tagged-although-all-permi/450746#450746